# Group by Oracle duda

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

tengo la siguiente duda:
sucede que necesito realizar la singuiente consulta(en oracle) para obtener unos totales de unos campos, pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
```

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT fecha, codigo, 
SUM(MTO_TASA_CONV_LIQ) as "total_mto_compensacion", 
sum(MTO_TASA) as "total_mto_tasa", 
sum(CDG_RAMT_TX_LOCAL) as "total_mto_venta",
count(*) as "total_cant_trx"
FROM VENTAS
WHERE fecha= 32608 
group by fecha;
```

Las funciones de agregación en SQL nos permiten efectuar operaciones sobre un conjunto de resultados, pero devolviendo un único valor agregado para todos ellos. Es decir, nos permiten obtener medias, máximos, etc... sobre un conjunto de valores.

Las funciones de agregación básicas que soportan todos los gestores de datos son las siguientes:

> COUNT: devuelve el número total de filas seleccionadas por la consulta.
>
> MIN: devuelve el valor mínimo del campo que especifiquemos.
>
> MAX: devuelve el valor máximo del campo que especifiquemos.
>
> SUM: suma los valores del campo que especifiquemos. Sólo se puede utilizar en columnas numéricas.
>
> AVG: devuelve el valor promedio del campo que especifiquemos. Sólo se puede utilizar en columnas numéricas.

Comment: te falta la columna `codigo` en el `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Significa que los campos que no son sumados en tu consulta necesitan ser agrupados, en tu caso estas agrupando por `fecha` pero te falta agrupar por el campo `codigo`:

```
 SELECT fecha, codigo, 
  SUM(MTO_TASA_CONV_LIQ) as "total_mto_compensacion", 
  sum(MTO_TASA) as "total_mto_tasa", 
  sum(CDG_RAMT_TX_LOCAL) as "total_mto_venta",
  count(*) as "total_cant_trx"
FROM VENTAS
WHERE fecha= 32608 
GROUP BY fecha,codigo;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me podrias dar un poco de contexto por que los campos que estan en el SUM no es necesario ser agregados  en el group by y solamente los 2 primeros en este caso

Comment: Por que sum ya es una funcion de agregacion